# Python import : AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'test'

Tags: python, python-import

I think that's stupid problem, but I can't figure out why I get the following

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'test'
```

when running my **test3.py**.

Here is my project tree :

```
.
├── __init__.py
├── test3.py
└── testdir
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test.py
```

My **test3.py** :

```
#!/usr/bin/python                                                          

import testdir

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(testdir.test.VAR)
```

My **test.py** :

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os

VAR=os.path.abspath(__file__)
```

I also tried to import my **VAR** this way :

```
from testdir.test import VAR
```

**EDIT:** Now this one works -thanks to @user2357112- but I would still like to know how to import the whole test.py file without a `from ... import ...` if it is possible. :)

And I tried a `import ..testdir` to do a relative import but I got a `SyntaxError`.

And if I try `import testdir.test` I get a `NameError: name'test' is not defined`.

How could I import this file? I'm a bit confused.

**EDIT bis :**

I apologize, when I tried `import testdir.test`, I also modified `print(testdir.test.VAR)` to `print(test.VAR)`.

That was the problem, my bad.

with :

```
#!/usr/bin/python                                                          

import testdir.test

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(testdir.test.VAR)
```

It works perfectly, I though that importing `testdir.test` made `test` exist alone (and not `testdir.test`) in the scope.

Sorry for the inconvenience. :S

Comment: Is `vAR` capitalized like that in your actual file?

Comment: My bad, you're right. Now `from testdir.test import VAR` works, thank you.
But how could I import the whole file without using a `from ... import ...`?

Comment: `import testdir.test`. Importing a package doesn't automatically load its submodules.

Comment: I tried this but I got a NameError.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally succeed to make it work this way :

```
#!/usr/bin/python                                                          

import testdir.test

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(testdir.test.VAR)
```

I erroneously modified `print(testdir.test.VAR)` to `print(test.VAR)` when I tried with `import testdir.test`. So I had this NameError.

My bad.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `from .test import VAR` to testdir/**init**.py. Then `import testdir
print testdir.VAR` in test3.py might work. I agree it is more of a workaround than solution.

Comment: This workaround works, indeed, thank you. :) I note this way to do, I didn't know it (I don't understand everything about imports).
But you're right : that's a workaround, isn't it dirty to put such imports in the **__init__.py**?
Anyway I finally found the problem (and I made a mistake in my question, so nobody would have be able to give me the answer to my problem, my bad :S).

Comment: No it is not 'dirty' per se to put imports in init file, infact the name suggests it is for initialisation of a package. It provides a sort of encapsulation, in which users of the package don't need to know about the internal structure and modules of the package. With that said, importing everything in init do clutters the namespace. So use it wisely.

Answer (score 1):

For adding the whole file with out using import statement, you can use [execfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#execfile)

Comment: I didn't know this one, thank you. But if I use it, it may, in some cases, erase some objects. I'll use it for something else though.

Answer (score 1):

I know this one is old, but I had the same error relating to `argparse`. I had an instance where you'd run the script and pass `test` if you want to run tests (might be a weird way to do it, but I am new to this!). It would pass `test` to `unittest.main()` as well. I fixed it with this:

```py
unittest.main(argv=['_'])
```

Below is what I had when it was working:

```py
from tests import *

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparser = parser.add_subparsers(dest='command', title='Commands')
subcommand_parser = subparser.add_parser('test')
args.parse_args()

if args.command == 'test':
  unittest.main(argv=['_'])
```

This also helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52369043/13752446

Comment: Hello and welcome on Stack Overflow.

This rather sounds as an AttributeError and is kinda off-topic.

I'd suggest rather making a separate issue ( _assuming the question hasn't been asked yet_ , which is quite possible) describing the problem, the detailed error, the code giving the error, and then answering your own post with the solution you found.