# python3 for unit test: AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute "kernel..."

Tags: python, jupyter, python-unittest

I am practicing the unittest for python and it always directed to a JSON file:

## Unittest code

```
import unittest
from name_function import get_formatted_name
class NamesTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_first_last_name(self):
        formatted_name=get_formatted_name("allen","park")
        self.assertEqual(formatted_name,"Allen Park")

unittest.main()
```

## ERROR

```
/Users/xxx/Library/Jupyter/runtime/kernel-0eacd257-bf93-4c0f-843c-2e8a96377a17
(unittest.loader._FailedTest)

AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute
'/Users/xxx/Library/Jupyter/runtime/kernel-0eacd257-bf93-4c0f-843c-2e8a96377a17'
```

The traceback is：

```
    SystemExit                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-1-15fe4fc5728d> in <module>()
         20         self.assertIn(response,my_survey.responses)
         21 
    ---> 22 unittest.main()

    /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/unittest/main.py in __init__(self, module, defaultTest, argv, testRunner, testLoader, exit, verbosity, failfast, catchbreak, buffer, warnings, tb_locals)
         93         self.progName = os.path.basename(argv[0])
         94         self.parseArgs(argv)
    ---> 95         self.runTests()
         96 
         97     def usageExit(self, msg=None):

    /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/unittest/main.py in runTests(self)
        256         self.result = testRunner.run(self.test)
        257         if self.exit:
    --> 258             sys.exit(not self.result.wasSuccessful())
        259 
        260 main = TestProgram

    SystemExit: True
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Have a look at "https://medium.com/@vladbezden/using-python-unittest-in-ipython-or-jupyter-732448724e31"

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(argv=['first-arg-is-ignored'], exit=False)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work, still reporting the same error...

Answer (score 2):

using following:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

It worked, but was failing before due to a mirror typo. I replaced:

```
self.asertEqual
```

with:

```
self.assertEqual
```